# upload multiple files using patch parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parameters, upload, patch

[image]I want to upload multiple Patch using patch file parameter in jenkins and also the no. of file to be uploaded is dynamic.
I want to make the same multiple file upload UI as its there while uploading files in gmail.
I want to add an attach a file button which will upload the file at that time only and another option for browsing next file comes up.
can somebody help?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand completely. You want just a "file upload" parameter that will upload file into a  some folder on the jenkins?

Comment: Jenkins have a patch File parameter already but that's work for the specified number of parameters i.e we have to configure before hand only that one has to upload 1,2,3 or n no of patch file and accordingly include that parameter that number of times.
But I want to have one button infront of this file parameter which dynamically can upload any no of files without configuring before hand.

One more concern is that these files get uploaded once we click on build button but I want to upload before only for that thing I need one button to upload file.

Is your understanding clear now?

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks :) I will take a look during a day

Comment: You can't upload a multiple patch files in single `patch file as parameter` parameter. It is simply unsupported by a plugin. In my opinion you have to fork it and to fix per your wish

Comment: Any other alternatives to accomplish the same?